# How to stop TFS 2012 users from seeing security settings

Tags: security, version-control, tfs, source-control-explorer

I created a user and added them to the 'Contributors' group so they can access code and change  items. However, I don't want them to see any security settings. As of right now, using just the contributors group they can go to the web access portal and see all the security settings (even though they cannot modify them). I do not want them to see ANY security settings or groups. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create `new custom Group TFS` and disable permission : `View project level information`.

he will have this message if he clicks : `"TF50309: the following account does not have sufficient ... "`